# Field 'age2' can only be read from 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' form content

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, spray

Could you guys tell me why following form of extraction works for both `multipart/form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests

```
formFields("firstName"?, "age2"?, "sex", "vip"?) {
  (firstName : Option[String], age2, sex, vip) =>
    complete(firstName + "." + age2 + "." + sex + "." + vip)
}
```

but this, seemingly equal, version of code

```
formFields('firstName :: ("age2".as[Int]) :: ('sex?) :: ("VIP" ? false) :: HNil) {
  (firstName : String, age2 : Int, sex : Option[String], vip : Boolean) =>
    complete(firstName + "." + age2 + "." + sex + "." + vip)
}
```

doesn't work when request is `multipart/form-data` encoded.

Server returns following error:

```
There was a problem with the requests Content-Type:
Field 'age2' can only be read from 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' form content
```

I see a call-stack to `spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FormField.fail` but my Scala skills are not strong enough to decipher it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Implementing a default unmarshaler for int" can be done  like this:

```
object JsonImplicits extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val IntUnmarshaller = Unmarshaller.delegate[String, Int](MediaRanges.`*/*`) { _.toInt }
}
```

And making sure its in scope before your route definition by adding the import right before: `import JsonImplicits._`

Answer (score 0):

Turned out there is no default unmarshaler for `Int`. So if you implement one it all works.

Not sure why it wasn't done by maintainers in the first place.